# Identify the large central plant with sword-shaped leaves in this arrangement?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

We've got this huge arrangement for decoration yesterday. I cannot identify the huge plant in the center. Please give me the name of the plant and any tips on how to keep the arrangement alive for a long time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We have a policy of asking about just one plant type per [tag:identification] question; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for details. I edited your post to focus on the large central plant since that's what's identified in the answer you got. Please ask new questions for the other plants that you're interested in.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The large plant in the middle is *Yucca elephantipes*. It's a very strong plant often used as houseplant. It can very well handle drought and likes a lot of sun as well, but in the half shade it will be happy as well. It doesn't like wet feet (too much water) or frost. See [here](https://www.ourhouseplants.com/plants/yucca) for more info about the plant.